# Assigning names to large objects appears to increase memory usage considerably

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, memory-management, memory-profiling

Usually, when I need to invoke a complicated formula, I break it down into two or more lines to make the code more comprehensible. However, when profiling some code that calculates [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation), I discovered that doing this appears to increase my code's memory use. Here's a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def fun1():
    #very large datasets (~750 mb each)
    predicted = np.random.rand(100000000)
    observed = np.random.rand(100000000)
    #calculate residuals as intermediate step
    residuals = observed - predicted
    #calculate RMSE
    RMSE = np.mean(residuals **2) ** 0.5
    #delete residuals
    del residuals

@profile
def fun2():
    #same sized data
    predicted = np.random.rand(100000000)
    observed = np.random.rand(100000000)
    #same calculation, but with residuals and RMSE calculated on same line
    RMSE = np.mean((observed - predicted) ** 2) ** 0.5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun1()
    fun2()
```

Output:

```
Filename: memtest.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     5     19.9 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
     6                             def fun1():
     7    782.8 MiB    763.0 MiB        predicted = np.random.rand(100000000)
     8   1545.8 MiB    762.9 MiB        observed = np.random.rand(100000000)
     9   2308.8 MiB    763.0 MiB        residuals = observed - predicted
    10   2308.8 MiB      0.1 MiB        RMSE = np.mean(residuals ** 2) ** 0.5
    11   1545.9 MiB   -762.9 MiB        del residuals


Filename: memtest.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    13     20.0 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    14                             def fun2():
    15    783.0 MiB    762.9 MiB        predicted = np.random.rand(100000000)
    16   1545.9 MiB    762.9 MiB        observed = np.random.rand(100000000)
    17   1545.9 MiB      0.0 MiB        RMSE = np.mean((observed - predicted) **
 2) ** 0.5
```

As you can see, the the first function (where the calculation is split) appears to require an additional ~750 mb at peak- presumably the cost of the `residuals` array. However, both functions require the array to be created- the only difference is that the first function assigns it a name. This is contrary to my understanding of the way memory management in python is supposed to work.

So, what's going on here? One thought is that this could be some artifact of the memory_profiler module. Watching the Windows task manager during a run indicates a similar pattern (though I know that's not a terribly trustworthy validation). If this is a "real" effect, what am I misunderstanding about the way memory is handled? Or, is this somehow numpy-specific?

Comment: (Also, not related to the memory usage, but you've got the operators in the wrong positions if you want to calculate a root mean square. Currently, you're taking the mean, then the square, then the root. You want to do square, then mean, then root. Otherwise, you're just getting the absolute value of the mean.)

Comment: @user2357112 you're completely correct, I put the parentheses wrong. I slightly panicked that I might have the same problem in my actual code and all my results thus far could have been off, but it was just an error I made when writing this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memory_profiler`'s "Mem usage" columns tells you the memory usage after each line completes, not the peak memory usage during that line. In the version where you don't save `residuals`, that array is discarded before the line completes, so it never shows up in the profiler output.

Comment: So to clarify- both functions peak at ~2300 mb, but profile "misses" the peak in the second function?

Comment: @Joe: With the corrected order of operations, they actually peak higher than that, since both `residuals` and its square must be alive at the same time. You could use `dot` to sum as you square, reducing the memory usage. Still, while the version with the extra variable has a few more objects' lifetimes overlapping, the effect is negligible, since it's just a few extra scalars. The two versions have roughly equal peak memory usage.